# Issue packaging a Windows Phone 8 app

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8-emulator

I just installed Visual Studio 2013 on my machine (which runs Windows 8.1 Enterprise Build 9600). I checked to include the Windows Phone 8 SDK option during install.

[image]

Once complete, I launched VS and tried a new Windows Phone App project.

[image]

Created and built fine. However. when I tried to run on the emulator, I get the error:

`Xap packaging failed. Cannot access a closed Stream.`

... and ...

`Could not find file 'c:\users\wade\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\DataBoundApp1\DataBoundApp1\obj\Debug\XapCacheFile.xml'. Please rebuild the solution and try again.`

Tried a clean and rebuild but still occurs. Also happens with the data bound app project.

So, I tried installing some of the SDK updates found here: http://developer.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk. All installed without a problem; however, when I tried again I got the same error.

Note: the emulator starts and runs just fine. The problem is creating the phone package and deploying to the emulator.

I'm not sure how to fix. Anyone have this issue?

UPDATE:

I have tried reinstalling the Windows Phone 8.0 SDK and all the updates. I should note that I also have VS 2012 installed and I also cannot create a Windows Phone 8 app in VS2012.

Here's an image of the WP8 stuff installed:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this issue by downloading the full Windows Phone 8.0 SDK ISO and installing (followed by a repair on the two updates).

I wish I could better explain how my machine got into this state. My suspicion is it's because I already had VS2012 installed on the machine and VS got into a confused state.

Total time spent? 4-5 hours.